# How to map cmd+s to save all?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm developing some front-end project with the help of `Yeoman`.

I run the developing webserver by `grunt server`and, because there is `livereload.js` in the project, for watching files change and refreshing the webpage, sometimes, I need to modify multiple files for one purpose(.html, .css, .js ...) and it's kind of waste for browser when each file saves.

So is there a way for `MacVim`, map `cmd + s` to `:wa` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nnoremap <D-s> :wa` in your `.vimrc` should do the trick.

`nnoremap` means this mapping is only available in Normal mode, and is not recursive.

`:wa` means write all, i.e. save all the current open buffers.

If you don't want to use a new mapping, you can simply type `:wa` to achieve the same things, but this is a matter of preferences only.

Comment: i didn't success with `<D-s>`, or other pre-defined shorcuts, but with `<D-j>`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I came searching with the same question.

**tl;dr:** <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save all.

You *can*, supposedly, map `<D-s>` to `:wa` but it's not as simple as adding the mapping to your .gvimrc file. See the third bullet below.

From the [MacVim docs](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/fd916f58a3723000b9d7b2e0d5657d050e4af962/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt#L618):

> *cmd-key* *cmd-shortcuts*
>
> Creating key mappings that involve the Cmd key ( in Vim notation) can
>   sometimes be slightly involved.  Here are all the things you need to consider:
>
> - Make sure the shortcut is not used by a menu item by looking through the
>     menus.  If it is then you need to unbind it before you can map to it.  This
>     is described under the help for the |:macmenu| command.
> - Bindings to  are case sensitive:  is not the same as .  If
>     you want to map something to Cmd+Shift+d, then you need to use , not
>      or .
> - Some command key shortcuts are reserved by Mac OS X and cannot be mapped to
>     (e.g. ).  However, some of these shortcuts can be freed up in the
>     System Preferences under Keyboard (e.g. Cmd+Space).

The good news? In trying to sort this out I realized that MacVim is a very courteous **Mac**Vim indeed and implements, by default anyway, many standard Mac shortcuts including: <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for "Save All". Open MacVim, click the file menu and then hit the <kbd>option</kbd> key to see it in action.